# EasyPHP - is it possible to replace Webserver to Devserver?

Tags: easyphp, easyphp-devserver, easyphp-webserver

I'm wondering, wheter it's possible instead of two installed apps (*EasyPHP Deveserver & EasyPHP Webserver*) to have installed only one - *EasyPHP Devserver*. This app would be somehow modify to allow access from another computers:

- **A)** from LAN,
- **B)** from WAN.

I'm interested in both of solutions; is it somehow possible (*probably by the unoficiall way, because I didn't find it on settings*) - did anyone try to? (Or do I have to have *EasyPHP Devserver* for my PC and *EasyPHP Webserver* for access from 'everywhere'?)

The reason is, why I want to do it, is just for developing purposes (*and I read somewhere, that Devserver is for this more suitable and I don't wont to have two folders on Devserver and Webserver and copy the files everytime*).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

- open a file *httpd.conf*. It should be on folder *EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache\conf*.
- Add behind *Listen 127.0.0.1:80* line with your PC's IP, eg. *Listen 192.168.1.1:80*.
- Then everywhere within the document (approx 5 times) replace *127.0.0.1* to *192.168.1.1*.

Now it's working.